# Update Android studio 3.0 Beta 2 Error

Tags: android

After updating android studio 3.0 Beta2. I am receiving an error. Can someone help me how to resolve this ?. Your help would be appreciable.

Below is the exception I am facing at the start of the android studio.

```
    Error:Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException`enter code here`
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:98)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:94)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:255)
        at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:84)
        at
```

Before update that was working fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Error:Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException`enter code here`
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:98)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:94)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:255)
    at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:84)
    at
```

Its a known issue :[As Documented here](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/08/android-studio-30-beta-2.html)

Just do this simply

**Build > Clean Project** from the menu bar.

Then **sync your project** files with Gradle by clicking Sync Project from the toolbar.